# Адаптивность сайта, разница между браузерами

Tags: html, css

Вопрос в следующем - имеется сайт, нужно было изменить меню, думал что всё ок, проверил через window resize, через другой сервис, везде всё норм. У заказчика макбук, он зашел на сайт и говорит что меню не поменялось. Я попросил скриншот и действительно у него оно не изменилось. Сайт на html. Не знаю как бы проверить наверняка и как исправить.... Спасибо....

Comment: у него, видать, браузер safari

Comment: Проверьте как оно выглядит на webkit-браузерах, это можно сделать на сервисах типа browserstack

Comment: @Danyal7 Установите себе Safari и мониторьте

Comment: не пониманию почему при таких условиях работы, а именно кроссбраузерности и адаптивности, вы не воспользовались сборщиками (`GULP` / `WEBPACK`), которые автоматически сделают автопрефиксы за вас.